# windows 7 user contemporary limit on share directory

Tags: windows-7

I have a share directory on windows 7 and 11 workstations access on it, but probably the current connections are hanging and the 20 user contemporary limit is exceeded by windows. For this issue I set up a morning computer restart. The question is, which services I can restart without having to restart the whole computer?

Comment: Have a look on this [discussion](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-performance/how-to-restart-a-service-using-scheduled-task/3bcc640d-4984-44c1-99fa-e58dd2310196) you may get a idea.

Comment: Sorry I hurt the question. I edit my question.